# validation of form with Jquery within asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I am a beginner with `Jquery` and `asp MVC4` 
I use the Jquery validate plugin

```
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript">
```

**the code**

```
<script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery("#monFormulaire").validate({
              rules: {
                  "reclamation": {
                      "required": true,
                      "minlength": 4,
                      "maxlength": 60000
                  },
                  "cause": {
                      "required": true,
                      "minlength": 4,
                      "maxlength": 60000
                  },

                  "curative": {
                      "required": true,
                      "minlength": 4,
                      "maxlength": 60000
                  },

                  "Closing_date": {
                      "required": true,
                      "minlength": 1,
                      "maxlength": 60000
                  }
              },
              submitHandler: function (form) { /* envoyer Mail*/
                  mailJob();
              }
          });
      });
```

```
        <button type="submit" value="Page5" name="btnPage1" style="margin-left:1%" class="backRow" ></button>

  <table border="1"  class="mytab" style="margin: auto;">
      formulaire .
 </table>

</form>
```

The validation runs in the right way but the Action in the server side is not invoked 
anyone have any Idea ???

Comment: We would need to see your code to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The action on the server side won't be invoked until you've passed client-side validation.

Comment: the validation in the client side work fine
submitHandler: function (form) { /* envoyer Mail*/
                  mailJob();
              }
this function is invoked but only server side is not invoked

Comment: @slatniawadii and when you've filled in your form correctly, and client-side validation is passed, what happens then?

Comment: nothing
but when I remove the script of validation all run ok 
I think it is prob of this bad plugin I will try to develop my own

Answer (score 1):

The action on the server side won't be invoked until you've passed client-side validation

Comment: yes I know I am sorry for not giving you alot of details because it's not my code I just try to repaire it it is full of errors 
 but in this code all run good when I move this code 
submitHandler: function (form) { /* envoyer Mail*/
                  mailJob();
              }
I add it just to run a javascript fuction if form valid

Answer (score 1):

**Disable** your client validation first and make sure that when your form is submitted, it invoke the action with the HttpPost attribute on you controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction()
```

Once this is working, re-enable your client validation and add

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

It will also help if you can use [Chrome Dev Tools: Networking and the Console](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console/) to check your traffic.

**Edit**: Add `form.submit();` at the end of your mailJob() function. Your initial form submit was consumed by the submitHandler and no longer applies to your form.

Comment: thank you rachid 
as I say at first I am a beginnner, 
I have located the probleme is in 
submitHandler: function (form) { /* envoyer Mail*/
                  mailJob();
              }
I wanna to excute this function when my form is valid

Comment: the probleme come with this methode 
submitHandler: function (form) { /* envoyer Mail*/
                  mailJob();
              }
it works fine when I remove that

Comment: Please comment out the mailJob();
`/*mailJob();*/`
If your code works then it means you have something wrong in your mailJob() function. It would be helpful if you can list the code for that one as well.

Comment: Do you have a `mailJob()` function defined somewhere in your code?

Comment: yes 
and it works fine but it prevents the action methode to be excuted

Comment: OK, The [submitHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) replaces the default submit. meaning you initial form submit will not execute. What you need to do is add `form.submit();` at the end of your `mailJob()` function.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to flag this as your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is your < form ... > node definition?

Did you define a target, a method (get/post)?

Note: sometimes, you could also need to disable request validation if you send strange data (like code, SQL etc.) in your form. To do that, put validateRequest="false" on your page definition in your ASPX file:

*<@ Page [...]* **validateRequest="false"** *[...] %>*

Note 2: don't forget to remove validateRequest="false" if it's not the answer - it could give you security issues.

Comment: thank you for answering me 
yes I just put a little bit of my code because satckoverflow don't allow to post a lot of code 
all run good when I remove this part of code 


submitHandler: function (form) { /* envoyer Mail*/
                  mailJob();
              }

Comment: this is a function to be run after validate form just before calling the server side